# Project Nested values in KQL from target resources

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am new to KQL, struggling to project values inside target resources but not able to retrieve the required values can you please help me below.

```
AuditLogs
| where ActivityDisplayName contains "Update user" and InitiatedBy contains "Testuser"
| where TargetResources contains "Id=xxxxxxxx"
```

wanted to project id and userprinciplename which are coming inside the targetresources, attached screenshot below link for reference

https://ibb.co/DpzZkks

Sample Json

```
[{
    "id": "xyz",
    "displayName": null,
    "type": "User",
    "userPrincipalName": "ABC",
    "modifiedProperties": [{
            "displayName": "xxxxxx",
            "oldValue": "xxxxx",
            "newValue": "yyyyy"
        },
        {
            "displayName": "xxxxx",
            "oldValue": "[{xxxx}]",
            "newValue": "[{xxxx}]"
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Included Updated Properties",
            "oldValue": null,
            "newValue": "xxxxx"
        },
        {
            "displayName": "TargetId.UserType",
            "oldValue": null,
            "newValue": "\"Member\""
        }
    ],
    "administrativeUnits": []
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `TargetResources` is of type `string`, you can use `parse_json()` to make it of type `dynamic`, then access its properties as follows:

```
| extend TargetResources = parse_json(TargetResources)
| project A = tostring(TargetResources.PropertyA),
          B = tolong(TargetResources.PropertyB),
          C = TargetResources.PropertyC
```

if `TargetResources` is already of type `dynamic`, you can simply access its properties as shown above, without having to invoke `parse_json`().

relevant documentation topics:

- [the `dynamic` data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/dynamic)
- [the `parse_json()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parsejsonfunction)

for example:

```
print input = '{"key1":1, "key2":"value2", "key3":{"key4":4.4}}'
| extend input = parse_json(input)
| project v1 = tolong(input.key1),
          v2 = tostring(input.key2),
          v4 = todouble(input.key3.key4)
```

| v1 | v2 | v4 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | value2 | 4.4 |

**UPDATE**, *based on the provided data sample*

when dealing with arrays, you can use [`mv-expand`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mvexpandoperator) or [`mv-apply`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/mv-applyoperator) to expand elements in the arrays for further processing

examples:

examples:

```
print TargetResources = dynamic([{
    "id": "xyz",
    "displayName": null,
    "type": "User",
    "userPrincipalName": "ABC",
    "modifiedProperties": [{
            "displayName": "xxxxxx",
            "oldValue": "xxxxx",
            "newValue": "yyyyy"
        },
        {
            "displayName": "xxxxx",
            "oldValue": "[{xxxx}]",
            "newValue": "[{xxxx}]"
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Included Updated Properties",
            "oldValue": null,
            "newValue": "xxxxx"
        },
        {
            "displayName": "TargetId.UserType",
            "oldValue": null,
            "newValue": "\"Member\""
        }
    ],
    "administrativeUnits": []
}])
| mv-expand TargetResources
| project TargetResources.id, TargetResources.userPrincipalName
```

| TargetResources_id | TargetResources_userPrincipalName |
| --- | --- |
| xyz | ABC |

```
print TargetResources = dynamic([{
    "id": "xyz",
    "displayName": null,
    "type": "User",
    "userPrincipalName": "ABC",
    "modifiedProperties": [{
            "displayName": "xxxxxx",
            "oldValue": "xxxxx",
            "newValue": "yyyyy"
        },
        {
            "displayName": "xxxxx",
            "oldValue": "[{xxxx}]",
            "newValue": "[{xxxx}]"
        },
        {
            "displayName": "Included Updated Properties",
            "oldValue": null,
            "newValue": "xxxxx"
        },
        {
            "displayName": "TargetId.UserType",
            "oldValue": null,
            "newValue": "\"Member\""
        }
    ],
    "administrativeUnits": []
}])
| mv-expand TargetResources
| mv-expand TargetResources.modifiedProperties
| project TargetResources_modifiedProperties
```

| TargetResources_modifiedProperties |
| --- |
| { "displayName": "xxxxxx", "oldValue": "xxxxx", "newValue": "yyyyy" } |
| { "displayName": "xxxxx", "oldValue": "[{xxxx}]", "newValue": "[{xxxx}]" } |
| { "displayName": "Included Updated Properties", "oldValue": null, "newValue": "xxxxx" } |
| { "displayName": "TargetId.UserType", "oldValue": null, "newValue": ""Member"" } |

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, i have altered the query with the given details, i am getting the output as null but it displays no of rows   https://ibb.co/dmFm2GH

Comment: updated sample Json in question, also need to fetch id and username from the above json

Comment: please see **update** in answer